# How to prevent padding to propagate to embedded tables

Tags: jquery, css

The jquery treetable uses

```
table.treetable tbody tr td {
  ...
  padding: .3em 1em;
  ...
}
```

I wonder how I can prevent the propagation of `padding-left` of 1em to sub-tables:

```html
    <table class="treetable">
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>
          <table class="inner"><tr><td class='nopad'>content</td></tr></table>
        </td></tr>
      </tbody>  
    </table>
```

I want the `<td class='nopad'>` to have  `padding-left : 0px;`. I tried several things, i.e. `.nopad {  padding-left: 0px; }` but it seems the padding from the treetable propagates and overrides any settings.

Comment: `selector1 > selector2` makes the rule only apply if the child is a direct child of the parent.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set your padding value(s) back to `initial` for the nested `td`. It's semantic in that it doesn't require you to change the DOM by adding additional classes.

```
table.treetable tbody tr td td {
  padding: initial;
}
```